# Show that if a complex polynomial is such that all its zeros have negative real part, then the zeros of its derivative also have negative real part.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $P(z)$ be a complex polynomial whose zeros all have a negative real part. Show that the zeros of $P'(z)$ all have negative real part.

I've thought about factoring $P(z)$ into linear factors, or maybe induction. But I can't seem to get that to work.

It was also suggested that I try doing the "logarithmic derivative" after I factor. I.e., taking the derivative of $ln(P(z))$. But it's not clear to me how this helps, since logarithms over the complex plane don't necessarily "split" across multiplication; i.e., $Ln(zw) \neq Ln(z)+ Ln(w)$.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is a direct consequence of the [Gauss–Lucas theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem): the roots of $P'$ are in the convex hull of the roots of $P$. The Wikipedia link has a proof of it involving the logarithmic derivative.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

So, We haven't covered Guass Lucas yet.

Is there a different way of thinking of this problem that doesn't require the theorem? Or perhaps a way of arguing for the desired result that borrows from the theorem, without using it directly?

Comment: @Bears I don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily done directly: let $z_k=x_k+iy_k, x_k \le 0$ the roots of $P$ and $z=x+iy, x>0$ (here we can use strict inequality/$\le$ the other way too of course so we can have $x_k <0, x \ge 0$).

Then $P(z) \ne 0$ and $\Re{\frac{P'(z)}{P(z)}}=\Re{\sum{\frac{1}{z-z_k}}}=\sum{\frac{x-x_k}{|z-z_k|^2}}>0$ since all $x-x_k>0$, hence $P'(z) \ne 0$ and we are done!